# Office 2019 - Language pack can't be installed on the selected update Channel

Tags: microsoft-office

I installed Office 2019 from Channel PerpetualVL2019, and try to install language packs, downloaded from here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

"This product can't be installed on the selected update channel."

Comment: You might try to change channels for this ([link](https://erwinbierens.com/switch-office-2016-to-monthly-targeted-channel/)).

Comment: @harrymc Monthly? Where does Microsoft stress this?

Comment: Monthly is simply because it's relatively up-to-date.